# override MenuLinkTree Block

Tags: 8, blocks

I want to override the block menu behavior, but i don't know how to do that, because the menu block are created dynamically.

I know add some block with the block plugin, like this :

```
/** 
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "system_name_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("my Block"),
 * )
 */
```

But i don't find how the core deal to create dynamic block for the Menu link tree.

I ever know that i have to override this class to get the espected behavior :
Drupal/Menu/MenuLinkTree.

But Now i've to know how to create dynamically some block to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu block is defined in the core module `system`.

Here you can see how the menu tree is set when creating the object:

```
core/modules/system/src/Plugin/Block/SystemMenuBlockTest.php:

namespace Drupal\system\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuActiveTrailInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTreeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a generic Menu block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "system_menu_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Menu"),
 *   category = @Translation("Menus"),
 *   deriver = "Drupal\system\Plugin\Derivative\SystemMenuBlock"
 * )
 */
class SystemMenuBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The menu link tree service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTreeInterface
   */
  protected $menuTree;
  ...
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, MenuLinkTreeInterface $menu_tree, MenuActiveTrailInterface $menu_active_trail) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->menuTree = $menu_tree;
    $this->menuActiveTrail = $menu_active_trail;
  }
```

How to use your own menu tree in a menu block you can see in this test:

```
core/modules/system/src/Tests/Block/SystemMenuBlockTest.php
```

Example from SystemMenuBlockTest.php. A menu that was created before is put in a block config:

```
$block = Block::create(array(
      'plugin' => 'system_menu_block:' . $this->menu->id(),
      'region' => 'footer',
      'id' => 'machinename',
      'theme' => 'stark',
    ));
```

Comment: So i've to make my own MenuBlock, base on SystemMenuBlock, right?

Comment: Yes, you could do this, but see the second part of my answer, it might be easier to use a block config entity and put your menu link tree in there. I put an example in the answer.

Comment: Oh ok, it look like simple. I'm sorry but i'm realy new in drupal : where could it put this code ? (creating a dynamics block) . In need one block by menu's id.

Comment: I'm ansering miself :
As i wanted a distinct block automaticaly created from the MenuTreeStorage as the actual MenuTreeBlock does, i've to create My own menuBlock... but without forgot to use the deriver !  
"deriver = "Drupal\system\Plugin\Derivative\SystemMenuBlock""